# Using presto to query from Hive external table: Invalid UTF-8 start byte

Tags: hive, hdfs, presto

I just installed presto and when I use the presto-cli to query hive data, I get the following error:

```
~$ presto --catalog hive --schema default
presto:default> select count(*) from test3;

Query 20171213_035723_00007_3ktan, FAILED, 1 node
Splits: 131 total, 14 done (10.69%)
0:18 [1.04M rows, 448MB] [59.5K rows/s, 25.5MB/s]

Query 20171213_035723_00007_3ktan failed: com.facebook.presto.hive.$internal.org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa5
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@6eb5bdfd; line: 1, column: 376]
```

The error only happens if I use aggregate function such as count, sum, etc.
But when I use the same query on Hive CLI, it works (but take a lot of time since it converts the query into a map-reduce job).

```
$ hive
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.4.2.0-258/0/hive-log4j.properties
hive> select count(*) from test3;
...
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 17 minutes 56 seconds 600 msec
Ended Job = job_1511341039258_0024
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 87  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 1076.6 sec   HDFS Read: 23364693216 HDFS Write: 9 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 17 minutes 56 seconds 600 msec
OK
51751422
Time taken: 269.143 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

The point is the same query works on Hive but not on Presto and I could not figure out why. I suspect it is because the 2 json library using on Hive and on Presto are different, but I'm not really sure.
I created the external table on Hive with the query:

```
hive> create external table test2 (app string, contactRefId string, createdAt struct <`date`: string, timezone: string, timezone_type: bigint>, eventName string, eventTime bigint, shopId bigint) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/data/data-new/2017/11/29/';
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please run CLI with `--debug` flag and post your problem to presto user list (https://groups.google.com/group/presto-users). This kind of problem is not fit for SO -- once your question will be properly defined, it will be also solved.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/v222wlsrtWo
I tried to post my problem here.

Comment: I see you solved your problem. Consider reporting your solution here so that there's no dangling question.

Answer (score 0):

posting this here for easy reference:

from [where OP documented a solution](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/v222wlsrtWo):

> I successfully fixed the problem by using this serde: https://github.com/electrum/hive-serde (add to presto at /usr/lib/presto/plugin/hive-hadoop2/ and to hive cluster at  /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/)